# Asciidoctor images that are links to the image

Tags: html, asciidoc

The following Asciidoc code creates an image (with suitable styling etc) such that if you click on it, you open the image:

```
image:./myimage.jpg[my alt text, role="my css styling", link="./myimage.jpg"]
```

Note the path to the jpg file `./myimage.jpg` is duplicated.  This is inelegant, invites typos, and if the path is long it can become quite inconvenient to maintain.

My question is this: 
*is there a neat way to achieve this effect that does not require duplicating the path to the image,* so that the path to the image is included precisely once in the code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't see how to do this in pure Asciidoc and would still welcome input on the matter.  In the meantime, I worked around the problem.

I'm in Jekyll so I used a Liquid template.  I placed a file `myimage` in the `_includes` directory

```
image:{{ include.p }}[{{ include.t }}, link="{{ include.p }}"]
```

and invoked it with

```
{% include myimage p="image-name.jpg" t="alt text" %}
```

This is actually a slight simplification.  In full, `myimage` is

```
[.cssstyling]#image:{{ include.p }}[{{ include.t }}, link="{{ include.p }}"]{% if include.c != null %}_{{include.c}}_{% endif %}#
```

and the invocation is one of the following:

```
{% include myimage p="image-name.jpg" t="alt text" %}
{% include myimage p="image-name.jpg" t="alt text" c="optional caption" %}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by defining an attribute:

```
:myimage: ./myimage.png
image::{myimage}[my alt text, role="my css styling", link="{myimage}"]
```

(also note: `::` instead of a single `:`).

This becomes something like the following when run through AsciiDoctor:

```
<div class="content">
<a class="image" href="./myimage.png"><img src="./myimage.png" alt="my alt text"></a>
</div>
```

This is obviously more text, but as you mentioned, maintenance (certainly for long file names or URLs to external images) becomes easier.

Be aware that the space between `:myimage:` and `./myimage.png` is required.

Also, if you redefine the attribute later in the document, it will only impact the next uses of the attribute. Thus,

```
:myimage: ./myimage.png
image::{myimage}[my alt text, role="my css styling", link="{myimage}"]

:myimage: ./myimage2.png
image::{myimage}[my second alt text, role="my css styling", link="{myimage}"]
```

will render two different images: the second attribute definition doesn't override the first one.
Though one may prefer different attribute names in such cases.

Comment: Thank you.  This is helpful.